# Reinstall indicator-appmenu package

Tags: 16.04, unity, indicator, globalmenu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and I disabled the global menu using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

How can I reactivate it ?

I've tied the command :

```
sudo apt-get install  indicator-appmenu
```

but with response:

```
Package indicator-appmenu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source 
E: Package 'indicator-appmenu' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Check your sources. Your 'main' is disabled. Enable it.

Comment: I don't understand what to do, would you please elaborate?

Comment: Open your `Software & Updates` control panel.  Locate the `Ubuntu Software` Tab. Check the top box in the list.